# sqlplus is not working

Tags: linux, docker, oracle12c

Thanks for reading!
Today i had a very strange issue.
Because my docker app just broken.. I never touched any file, just execute sqlplus, used it, then shut my Host OS.

So i tried to fix this issue. Here is a error.

```
[oracle@7e421c70357d ~]$ lsnrctl status

LSNRCTL for Linux: Version 12.1.0.2.0 - Production on 02-NOV-2017 16:31:09

Copyright (c) 1991, 2016, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Connecting to (ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=)(PORT=1521))
TNS-12541: TNS:no listener
 TNS-12560: TNS:protocol adapter error
  TNS-00511: No listener
   Linux Error: 111: Connection refused
[oracle@7e421c70357d ~]$ sqlplus
Error 6 initializing SQL*Plus
SP2-0667: Message file sp1<lang>.msb not found
SP2-0750: You may need to set ORACLE_HOME to your Oracle software directory
[oracle@7e421c70357d ~]$
```

So i check everything as i can.`ORACLE_HOME` is correct.
`ORACLE_HOME` is `/u01/app/oracle/product/12.1.0/dbhome_1`.

And there are lots of files and directories, so correct. Checked twice.

And i realize that there is no `sqlplus` folder in `ORACLE_HOME`.
I think sqlplus just gone, totally missing..
I don't know why this happened, no clue.

Edited..
I googled anything about my issue and i got this.
Directory: `/var/log/oracle-rdbms-server-12cR1-preinstall/results`

```
[root@7e421c70357d results]# ls
orakernel.log
[root@7e421c70357d results]# cat *
Adding group oinstall with gid 54321
Adding group dba
Adding user oracle with user id 54321, initial login group oinstall, supplementary group dba and  home directory /home/oracle
Changing ownership of /home/oracle to oracle:oinstall
Please set password for oracle user
uid=54321(oracle) gid=54321(oinstall) groups=54321(oinstall),54322(dba)
Creating oracle user passed 

Saving a copy of the initial sysctl.conf
Verifying  kernel parameters as per Oracle recommendations...
Adding fs.file-max = 6815744 
Adding kernel.sem = 250 32000 100 128 
Adding kernel.shmmni = 4096 
Adding kernel.shmall = 1073741824 
Adding kernel.shmmax = 4398046511104 
Adding kernel.panic_on_oops = 1 
Adding net.core.rmem_default = 262144 
Adding net.core.rmem_max = 4194304 
Adding net.core.wmem_default = 262144 
Adding net.core.wmem_max = 1048576 
Adding net.ipv4.conf.all.rp_filter = 2 
Adding net.ipv4.conf.default.rp_filter = 2 
Adding fs.aio-max-nr = 1048576 
Adding net.ipv4.ip_local_port_range = 9000 65500 
Setting kernel parameters as per oracle recommendations...
Altered file /etc/sysctl.conf
Saved a copy of the current file in /etc/sysctl.d/99-oracle-rdbms-server-12cR1-preinstall-sysctl.conf
Check /etc/sysctl.d for backups
Verifying & setting of kernel parameters passed 

Setting user limits using /etc/security/limits.d/oracle-rdbms-server-12cR1-preinstall.conf

Verifying oracle user OS limits as per Oracle recommendations...
Adding oracle soft nofile  1024
Adding oracle hard nofile  65536
Adding oracle soft nproc  16384
Adding oracle hard nproc  16384
Adding oracle soft stack  10240
Adding oracle hard stack  32768
Adding oracle hard memlock  134217728
Adding oracle soft memlock  134217728
Setting oracle user OS limits as per Oracle recommendations...
Altered file /etc/security/limits.d/oracle-rdbms-server-12cR1-preinstall.conf
Original file backed up at /var/log/oracle-rdbms-server-12cR1-preinstall/backup/Jun-01-2017-23-10-04
Verifying & setting of user limits passed 

/boot/grub/grub.conf not present.. ..
Verifying of boot parameters failed. 

Trying to add NOZEROCONF parameter...
Taking a backup of existing file to /etc/sysconfig/network.orabackup
Successfully added parameter NOZEROCONF to /etc/sysconfig/network
Setting /etc/sysconfig/network parameters passed 

Disabling Transparent Hugepages. 
Refer Oracle Note:1557478.1

Disabling defrag. 
Refer Oracle Note:1557478.1

Taking a backup of old config files under /var/log/oracle-rdbms-server-12cR1-preinstall/backup/Jun-01-2017-23-10-04 
Trying to add NOZEROCONF parameter...
Parameter added by previous preinstall rpm
Parameter already present
/boot/grub/grub.conf not present.. ..
Boot file modifications failed
```

Anyone have an idea to solve this issue, Please give me a hand.

Answer (score 0):

Use this command to find sqlplus. sqlplus is a binary command and it is always in a ../bin directory

$which sqlplus

Usually by default they are located over at this directory:

~/app/oracle/product/your_db_version/dbhome_1/bin/sqlplus

Go to that directory and make sure it has executable permission with something like this if it is there or not missing:

$cd ~/app/oracle/product/your_db_version/dbhome_1/bin/

$ls -la sqlplus

-rwxr-x--x. 1 oracle mygroup 9479 Mar 16  2015 sqlplus

Run this to be sure:

$sudo chmod 755 sqlplus

It is similar to 'sudo chmod u=rwx,go=rx'

Use this command to check your environment setting.

$echo PATH

Make sure you have something like this

/home/oracle/bin:/home/oracle/app/oracle/product/your_db_version/dbhome_1/bin

Add them to your environment if they are not listed.

$sudo vi ~/.bashrc

or

$sudo vi /etc/profile

I am hoping this will help. Good luck!

Comment: `/u01/app/oracle/product/12.1.0/dbhome_1`, this is my `$ORACLE_HOME`.

Comment: `which sqlplus` results `bash: which: command not found` as `oracle`.


`echo $PATH` results `/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/u01/app/oracle/product/12.1.0/dbhome_1/bin
` as `oracle`.

Comment: But `echo $PATH` results `/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin` as `root`.

`which sqlplus` results same.

Comment: sqlplus is supposed to be in your directory here

/u01/app/oracle/product/12.1.0/dbhome_1/bin 

Go in that directory.

Comment: Once you are in bin. look for the sqlplus command and type

ls -la sqlplus
Look if the executable permission is being disabled.

Comment: `[oracle@7e421c70357d bin]$ ls -la sqlplus
-rwxr-xr-x 1 oracle oinstall 9423 Jul 21  2014 sqlplus
` the `oracle` owns it and executable.
But still has same issue.